# How to Scroll a view only when fingers moved on a specified rect in scrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview.I want it to scroll only when I move my fingers in a particular region in the scrollview unlike the usual way.is it possible?. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Handle with touches, detect a swipe event and then scroll the ScrollView thro' coding.

Comment: Thanks. But I have solved it using one scroll view on another and keeping the user interaction enabled yes only for top scroll view.  content offset of both views are made equal in didscroll method.